# Rails: how to get object into setter method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, getter-setter

I'm trying to save attributes of associated model through a setter method.

**My code:**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :employee

    attr_accessor :company_id
    attr_accessor :employee_name

    def employee_name
      employee.try(:name)
    end

    def employee_name=(name)
      self.employee = Employee.find_or_create_by(name: name, 
         company_id: company_id.to_i) if name.present?
    end
end
```

This, however, this saves the attribute as `nil`.

Why does the `company_id` attribute become `nil`  when used inside the setter method?

Its value ís available in the model outside of the setter method.

```
validate :is_company_id_available

def is_company_id_available
    if company_id != nil
            errors.add(:task, "#{company_id.inspect}") 
        end
end
```

returns the correct `company_id` in the error message.

Also, manually defining `company_id = 1` inside de setter method saves just fine.

How should I correctly set the attribute inside the setter method?

EDIT:

Is it possible that the `company_id` attribute somehow needs to be set as an argument to this method?

Or perhaps I can update the `company_id` after the `employee` record is created.

Comment: I dont see employee_company_id being defined anywhere

Comment: @Vic, apologies. I'm passing the attribute in directly from the form using `attr_accessor`. This is not the best solution, but I'm trying to tackle one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Rails way* is by using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Employee
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end

Employee.create(name: 'max', tasks_attributes: [{ description: 'Fetchez La Vache' }])
```

You can of course also do the inverse:

```
class Task
   belongs_to :employee
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee
end
Task.create(description: 'Fetchez La Vache', employee_attributes: { name: 'max' })
```

If the nested attributes contain an id this will update the nested record.

```
@task = @employee.tasks.create(description: "Dot the T's")
@employee.update(tasks_attributes: [{ id: @task.id, description: "Cross the T's" }])
@task.reload.description == "Cross the T's" # true
```

A word of caution is however to avoid going to many layers down. You end up horrible over-bloated controllers and very complex logic.

While it might be possible to setup delegation as you have attempted its pretty messy and you have to remember that parent record must be inserted into the DB before the child record can get the `parent_id`.

---

Multilevel example

```
class Project
  has_many :projects
end

class Task
  belongs_to :employee
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee, reject_if: :employee_exists?

  def employee_exists?(attrs)
    return true if employee.any? # its set already
    e = Employee.find_by(name: attrs[:name] company_id: attrs[:company_id])
    employee = e if e
    e.any?
  end
end

class Employee
  has_many :tasks
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |p| %>
  <%= fields_for(:tasks) do |t| %>
     <p>Select an employee</p>
     <%= f.collection_select(:employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
     <p>Or create a new one</p>
     <%= fields_for(:employee) do |e| %>
       <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
       <%= f.collection_select(:company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You would usually combine this with a bit of javascript which grays out the employee fields when the user selects an existing record. However if you have the option it might be better to use AJAX to create the nested records instead.

That lets you create the user experience as a series of atomic transactions instead of one mega do or die form submission.

Comment: Hi @Max, thanks for your suggestion. I'm affraid this won't work, though. The form is created from @projects. I'm already using `accepts_nested_attributes` on my nested `Task` model. Each new `project` has many `tasks`, which should find or create one employee, hence the virtual attributes. Any suggestions on how to put the `company_id` variable into the setter method? Thanks again!

Comment: My guess is that it does not work since your setter is not guaranteed to run before the `company_id=` setter. I would really try to get it to work with accepts_nested_attributes or try a different solution altogether such as separate form submissions. As you can the whole timing and dependency resolution thing is not very easy to get right.

Comment: Ok. I understand you believe it is a timing issue. I initially thought it had to do with declaring the arguments correctly, but this is probably not correct then. I'll look into the accepts_nested_attributes_for approach you describe. This was supposed to be easy! ;-) Thanks again for taking the time to help. Cheerio

Comment: How I solved this is by adding a callback `before_save` and then updating the attribute seperately. This works (jay!) but is somewhat dirty. I will readup more about the `accepts_nested_attributes` in order to improve my code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

max's answer is the Railistic way of doing this.

But is `attr_accessor :company_id` really necessary? 
Try removing it or just use `read_attribute(:company_id).to_i` or `self[:company_id].to_i` instead.

[Edit]

I think your params should have `{task_attributes: {company_id: company_id}}`

or it's a problem that occurs only when `attributes=` is used.
You could override `attributes=` and play around it

```
def attributes=(task_attributes)
  binding.pry
end
```

[Edit 2]

Also make sure that `task_attributes: [:company_id]` is permitted in strong parameters

Comment: Hi @jmmaniego, thanks for your answer. `company_id` is permitted in the strong params, hence its availability in the `Task` model. `self.company_id` gives me the correct id, but `read_attribute(:company_id)` or `self[:company_id]` are both `nil` in my model. All are `nil` inside the setter method. Not sure about the `def attributes=`, I'll look into that! Is it possible that the `company_id` attribute somehow needs to be set as an argument to the setter method?